# Trouble accessing array - does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

I'm building an app using Typescript React in SharePoint SPFX. I'm trying to build a table using [material-table](https://material-table.com/) using the element found in an array.

In my `componentDidMount()` I have the following code to create my array.

```
public componentDidMount() { 

        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {

            const listItems = items.map((item) => {

                return {
                    UsersName: item.Title,
                    UserEmail: item.Email,
                    UserStatus: item.Status,
                    UserLocation: item.Location,                        
                }
            });
            console.log(listItems);


        });

}
```

And in my render I have this hard coded for now that display the table:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<ISigninLocationWebpartProps> {

    return (

        <div className={ styles.signinLocationWebpart }>

            <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>

            <MaterialTable
                title=""
                columns={[
                { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
                { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
                { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
                {
                    title: 'Birth Place',
                    field: 'birthCity',
                    lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
                },
                ]}
                data={[
                { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
                { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
                ]}        
                options={{
                filtering: true
                }}
            />


            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm trying to replace the data section with the elements in my `listItems` array. So I did something like `data={UserList}` or `data={this.UserList}` with errors on both. Do I need to set the state of the array to be able to access it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            UserList: []
        }

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        //suppose pnp obj's coming from props
        const { pnp } = this.props;
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
            const listItems = items.map((item) => {
                return {
                    UsersName: item.Title,
                    UserEmail: item.Email,
                    UserStatus: item.Status,
                    UserLocation: item.Location,
                }
            });


            this.setState({ UserList: [...listItems] });


        });

    }

    render(): React.ReactElement<ISigninLocationWebpartProps> {

        return (

            <div className= { styles.signinLocationWebpart } >

                <div style={ { maxWidth: "100%" } }>

                    <MaterialTable
                        title=""
                        columns = {
                            [
                                { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
                                { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
                                { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
                                {
                                    title: 'Birth Place',
                                    field: 'birthCity',
                                    lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
                                },
                                ]}
                        data = {this.state.UserList}
                        options = {
                            {
                                filtering: true
                            }
                        }
                    />

                    Debug: {JSON.stringify(this.state.UserList)}

                < /div>

            < /div>
    );

}

export default test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I set the state in my props and did your change. And now I'm getting this error in the console `_this.props.data is not a function at MaterialTable.` Also, when I console log `console.log(this.state.UserList);` in my public render it returns back an empty array.

Comment: I renamed the state variable above to UserList according to your question. I also added the line : Debug: {JSON.stringify(this.state.UserList)} to debug the data. Since the error w/ MaterialTable could be related to some other aspect with that component.

Comment: there it goes, I think your're right when I remove that table component and add the Debug it spits out the array and everything is in there. However when I add the table it gives me that same this.props.data error. Weird..

Comment: You should look for MaterialTable component documentation.

Comment: so I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation. I think it's the way this.prop.data is being invoked like a function. In the material-table.js this is the error I'm getting. Here is a link to a screen capture: `https://ibb.co/F5MLn06`